# Image manipulation on Google App Engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, image-processing

I just found out that PIL functions on Google App Engine (GAE) are limited to only some basic functions.

I'm attempting to deploy a GAE app which is able to add text over an image and it is not possible to use GAE's Images Python API.

So right now, I'm hoping to look for alternatives:

1. External service I can call to modify the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python 2.5 runtime only supports a limited set of operations through the Images API. However, the [python 2.7 runtime](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27.html#Configuring_Libraries) supports the full PIL suite.

Comment: All I have to do is to add a something to the app.yaml. Thanks!